# Is this doable with TFS Build Automation?

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

New to Build Automation with .NET projects and TFS 2013. Would like advice on whether it's worth spending the time to pursue further.

We have one solution for our core DLLs. Also one solution each for the main website, a portal site, and a few windows services. Various of the DLLS get compiled and distributed amongst the solution. So ideally the build would be a combination of compiling the DLLS, copying to the other solutions as needed, then build those projects. And at the end, move the compiled results to some ftp site.

Does this sound like the kind of thing TFS Build Automation can handle WITHOUT having to devote the next X months to writing custom tasks and so on, i.e. using as much out of the box functionality as possible?

Comment: The "distributed" adjective can be tricky: TFS Build puts all binaries in a single folder to simplify assembly lookup (References). If you have some hardcoded path or pre-/post-build action, you may face some issues.

Comment: Have you considered CCNET? You could setup a cruise control server, schedule your builds, and then setup post build tasks to run powershell scripts to do whatever you want.